# Jquery keypress method not working properly in Mozilla

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine IE9 and Chorme but not working in mozilla

```
$("#BasicSalary").keypress(function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode < 46 || event.keyCode > 57) {
            event.preventDefault();
           }
          else if (event.keyCode == 47) {
            event.preventDefault();
           }
       });
```

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `keyCode` to `which` and it'll be much more cross-browser compatible. You can add a fail-over to make it even more reliable:

```
$("#BasicSalary").keypress(function (e) {

    var keyCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode

    if (keyCode  < 46 || keyCode  > 57) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (keyCode  == 47) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $("#BasicSalary").keypress(function (event) {
      var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;

      if (keycode < 46 || keycode > 57) {
        event.preventDefault();
       }
      else if (keycode == 47) {
        event.preventDefault();
       }
   });
```